# Any advice on how to modify or improve my question for improved clarity

Tags: support, scope

What technologies and advances in current mathematical theory will be necessary to predict quantum probability with 100% Certainty?

If not is this off topic in a specific way?

Does the way this question is stated imply "sci-fi" technology.

Does the "technologies" part need to be left out?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, this site is for questions about physical principles, not specific technologies. We make these judgments on a case-by-case basis, so you may see some technology-related questions on the site that are perfectly fine, but this would not be one of them.

That being said, I would have to wonder what you mean by "predict quantum probability with 100% certainty." Are you asking about the ability to completely predict the behavior of a quantum system? That is impossible, so asking how to do it wouldn't be appropriate. (Although you can certainly ask *why* it is impossible.) Are you asking about the ability to predict the wavefunction? That we can already do, although it's impossible to compare it with measurements because you can't measure a wavefunction, at least not on a *single* quantum system. That's another one where you shouldn't ask how to do it, but you can ask why we can't measure a wavefunction on a single system. Or are you asking something about the accuracy of calculations in perturbation theory? In that case you would have to be more specific, and say what physical system you are talking about, because some of them can be solved and some of them can't.

Comment: The response I want to give would be 500 years ago you can't sail west from England and end up in china(you would fall off the world. 75 years ago you can not prove black holes. The we can or can not is relative on our ability to comprehend the "true" charastics of the object, theories in question.  Would it be the case to ask the why not and then build from there how overcomming this limitation with certain understanding being refined or re-written? Science future not fiction. May be a foolish hope or aspiration that we can overcome any obstacle. No matter how limiting at this time